# sent email with attachment in the local files directory

Tags: android, email, attachment, email-attachments

i successfully could export data as a csv file to the external storage directory and then send and receive it as attachment via email. the only problem was that this file then appears in a public directory, what's confusing and unnecessary (and also needs additional privileges).

so i tried to store that export file in the private files dir. it was possible for me to save the file to that directory, and open the email client (myMail and Gmail) and see the attachment with the correct file size information before sending it. but after sending it, i receive it without the attachment. is it possible to use the private file dir for this purpose?

```
String fileName = reportName + ".csv";
            try {
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = getApplication().openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
                fileOutputStream.write(sbCsv.toString().getBytes());
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                D.e(e);
            }

            Uri exportFile = null;
            File file = getApplication().getFileStreamPath(fileName);
            // File file = new File(getApplication().getFilesDir(), fileName);
            exportFile = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "testSubject");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, exportFile);
            String aEmailList[] = {"test@test.org"};
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            emailIntent.putExtra(
                    Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    Html.fromHtml(sbBody
                            .toString())
            );
            startActivityForResult(emailIntent, REQUESTCODE_SENTEMAIL);
```

Comment: Its amazing that the file size is ok. Try to change MODE_PRIVATE to MODE_WORLD_READABLE. Otherwise use a content provider.

Comment: thanks, this works, but MODE_WORLD_READABLE is depreciated, this is why i did not use it before. so i can try it with a content provider. i just wonder if this is really necessary as i just want to send an export file with email, and never need that file again after its sent.

Comment: Then place it in external cache memory. And delete the next day as i believe its to early to do that in onActivityResult. But you could try.

Comment: i did something like that before, but i also wanted to get rid of the extra permission.

Comment: Then try a content provider. Or neglect the deprecation.